# Derivation of 175 in MDRD Equation

Tags: creatinine, glomerular-filtration-grf

So the MDRD equation (The Modification of Diet in Renal Disease) estimates glomerular filtration using the formula:

eGFR (mL/min/1.73 m2) = 175 x (SCr)-1.154 x (Age)-0.203 x (0.742 if female) x (1.212 if African American)

Now I know the age, race, and sex parameters are based off of population data, but how is the 175 derived? Is it just a constant that makes the equation work, and if so, why not use different exponential values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I believe it might the be average male adult height in cm. That is why you multiply by 0.742 for females.